# Is it possible to load the CSS stylesheets applied to a DOM in node.js?

Tags: jquery, node.js

This is a snippet of what I'm trying to do at the moment:

```
var sys     = require("sys"),
    request = require("request"),
    $       = require("jquery"),
    uri     = 'http://' + process.argv[2];

request({uri:uri}, function (error, response, context) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log($('body', context).css('background'));
  }
})
```

Obviously, this just returns undefined; is there a way to apply the stylesheets defined in the link elements so that I can query them with jQuery?

Comment: So you want something to parse the contents of that URI and produce a DOM, and also parse and interpret the CSS, all in server-side node.js ... sounds like you need to integrate with WebKit somehow, because what you need is a browser.

Comment: Well I have the DOM interpreted already, hence I can select elements and get their relative attributes and values- I just can't get any styling other than inline styles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Pointy already *pointed* out (scnr) this is by no means trivial.

You need to:

1. Parse the CSS
2. Apply the rules to the DOM
3. Compute the current style based on the rules

Basically you need a browser rendering engine without the actual drawing, that will take **a lot** of code in JavaScript (50k LOC+ if one's lucky), you need to implement all the CSS versions, check the document type etc.

Right now the best thing one could do is to grab that stuff out of WebKit and bind it with V8 for a Node C extension. A pretty huge job, so unless you're willing to start this on your own, I guess you're out of luck.

Binding the things will take quite some effort, but it will still take way less time then writing the whole thing in JS from scratch (which will be horrible slow, even with the current increase in JavaScript performance).

Comment: Fair enough, as you said I'm thinking I'm out of luck- what I'm trying to do is pushed way out of scope with this taken into consideration. Thanks again Ivo!

Comment: FAO anyone else desiring this functionality, whilst it is by no means the same, I ended up opting for pulling a stylesheet and using regex to pull out the bits I needed. CSS is fairly easy to predict so I can get the data I need with an adequate level of accuracy. Code example at: http://logo.stevelacey.net

Answer (score 0):

Although not Node.js, this looks to now be possible via [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org).